# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null - style.display not working

Tags: javascript, java, css, spring, jsp

My requirement is I have a jsp page with Signup information. It will submit all values in controller and comes back to same "Signup.jsp" . Till this it is working. Now the requirement is , once it comes back in the same page , where I have set a parameter while redirecting from controller. In Jsp , the parameter gets validated and if the parameter comes from controller matched then one 'td' will be visible, which should not be visible when first time I send the Jsp to controller.

So here is the code, "signup.jsp" inside WebContent -> WEB-INF -> jsp(folder)

```
<html>
<head>
 <!-- So this script below actually checks if from controller "31012057" 
 value is coming or not. If matches then "id=phone" in table will be visible 
 which is hidden now -->

 <script type="text/javascript">
  var value=<%= request.getAttribute("parameter") %>
  if(value!=null && value==31012057)
  {
  alert("My Phone text box will be visible here.......");
  document.getElementById('phone').style.display = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('phoneTextBox').style.display = 'visible';
  }
 </script>
 </head>
 <body>
<form:form id="signup" method="post" action="signup" modelAttribute="signup" 
commandName="signup">

<table>
 <tr>
 <td>
        <form:label path="firstname">FirstName</form:label>
 </td>
 <td>
       <form:input path="firstname" name="firstname" 
            id="firstname"/>
 </td>
 </tr>

 <tr>
 <td id="phone" style=display:none>
         <form:label path="phone">Phone</form:label>
 </td>
 <td id="phoneTextBox" style=display:none>
         <form:input path="phone" name="phone" id="phone" />
 </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
  <form:button id="register" name="register">Register</form:button>
  </td>
  </tr>
 </table>
</form:form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

I saw some style error but could not get any solution in any site yet on how to make the phone number  visible once the form submits successfully and controller receives all information from jsp and return to "signup.jsp" again.

If anyone wants to execute, then here is the controller code.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
     public String signupPost(@ModelAttribute("signup") SignupPojo 
     signup,Model model) {

     int parameter=31012057;
     model.addAttribute("firstname", signup.getFirstname());
     model.addAttribute("parameter", parameter);
     return "signup";
```

The SignupPojo.java which is getters and setters,

```
     public class SignupPojo {

     private String firstname;
     private int phone;
     //getter setter
     }
```

The web.xml

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class> 
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>signup</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/signup</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

signup-servlet.xml which is inside WebContent -> WEB-INF

```
     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="GIVE YOUR CONTROLLER PACKAGE NAME "/>

    <bean 
  class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
   </bean>
    </beans>
```

It would be a great help.Thanks in advance.

==============================================================================
Alright, this is edit section. With help of @Ofisora and @Tahir Hussain Mir I resolved the issue. The solution is , I have placed the 'script' tag at the end of body section, right before closing 'body' because of loading issue. And I have changed 
     document.getElementById('phone').style.display = 'visible';
 to 
     document.getElementById('phone').style.display = 'block';

So this is solution for "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" , so changing the title, for anyone facing the same issue like me.

Comment: Is this because your code has `style=display:none` instead of `style="display:none"`?

Comment: @Ofisora . No,  style="display:none" does not resolve the issue.

Comment: Can you change `document.getElementById('phone').style.display = 'visible';
  document.getElementById('phoneTextBox').style.display = 'visible';` to `...display='block'`?

Comment: @Ofisora I didn't get your last question. The style=display:none was a typo . It is style="display:none" originally in my code. But this is not the solution. This style="display:none" is for hiding the 'td'. I want to make it visible once the form gets submit to controller and return in this page again. There document.getElementById('phone').style.display = 'visible'; is not working to make this 'td' visible.

Comment: `visible` is not the right value. It should be `block`.

Comment: @Ofisora ...display='block' is also not working :(

Comment: I also saw one error in chrome , it says "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null" . the error is in line document.getElementById('phone').style.display = 'block';

Comment: Can you print and see what is the value of `request.getAttribute("parameter")` after signup and also remember to use `===` not `==` in javascript to compare. If not try `"phone number"` in double quote?

Comment: @Ofisora it is "31012057" also the alert is showing properly.

Comment: @Ofisora Thanks to you too. display='block' actually works well, not visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The very simple solution for your problem is just put the script code at the end of your jsp file.
That is it.
I firstly thought, the conversion of `request.getAttribute` is the problem.
But after looking at your comments, i got that, your `DOM` is not known to the script. *That is why the error is "can't read the style id of null"*.
The reason is, scripts should always be written at the end so that they could know the DOM. Otherwise, you could use, window.onload as well in the beginning so that your script has a look at the complete DOM.

***So simply put the entire script tag at the end of the file.***

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.You have saved my life. But wondering how changing the position works?

Comment: @SharmisthaSakar i am happy that it worked for you. But, why you didn't accepted my answer?

Comment: I did now. Thank again.

Comment: my pleasure dear. ^_^ @SharmisthaSakar